# Force downloaded file only 1kb PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to set a file to force download using the following but the downloaded file is only 1kb and thus invalid:

```
$url = "/home/sites/url.com/to_download/$row[filename]";

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$row[filename]"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($url));
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
readfile($url);
```

The file is a zip file which is 121mb. The path is definitely correct.

Anything obviously wrong?

**UPDATE**

The screenshot below looks correct but still a 1kb download - I will stress, **the path and filename are correct**

[image]

Comment: Is it by chance a file with a PHP error message?

Comment: Can you share what `$row` is?

Comment: Inspect the contents of the downloaded file. Maybe it is the first part of the zip (you should be able to tell by the header), or it is (more likely) an error message or 404 page.

Comment: And if you inspect your variables before returning the file, you may find that the file name is wrong.

Comment: I'm with GolezTrol, this is almost certainly just the error codes being returned to you.

Comment: @Darren. It looks like a zipfile, but that is because of the content type headers that you always send. Please, just save the file and open it in Notepad++ or something, to see what is actually inside. Same goes for the file size. The file isn't downloaded yet, so the browser bases this information solely on the headers.

Comment: You've been given a couple of tips to get debug information. You've ignored them and posted a nice screenshot. Well, if your browser thinks it's a ZIP file, everybody else (including RAR Archiver) must be wrong.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks you for explaining that explicitly. I actually didn't know you could do that, this is a learning curve. What is says is: 
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 524288) (tried to allocate 126951424 bytes) in /home/sites/url.com/public_html/test.php on line 28 - do I take it this is a server error? That it only allows 0.4mb download? - Thanks again